# Android Right Align TabWidget

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, tabwidget

I want use tabs in my own android app but there is a problem for me. I try to do TabWidget alignment at right side so as first tab header placed at right side. I find some solution in web like setting TabWidget gravity to right , nested TabWidget in LinearLayout and setting it gravity to right, but them did't work.

This is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ir.andrun.tabbased.Main"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none">
                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:tag="tab0"
                            android:text="Tab 1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
                        <TextView
                            android:tag="tab1"
                            android:text="Tab 2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
                        <TextView
                            android:tag="tab2"
                            android:text="Tab 3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                </TabWidget>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Tab 1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Tab 2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Tab 3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is result :

[image]

Pleas somebody help me.

Tanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use `HorizontalScrollView`?

Use [Android Material Design working with Tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

Option 0: Try setting the tabhost to `android:gravity="end"`

Option 1: Try setting the tabhost to `android:layout_alignRight="true"` or `android:layoutParentEnd="true"`

Option 2: Add a space taker-upper before tabhost

```
<!-- Take up space -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
```

Hope one of those is what you are looking for.